# finding a power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

When you are given the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a matrix A and are asked to solve for A^3, for the formula A = PDP^-1 is your diagonal matrix the identity matrix with the eigenvalues swapped with the 1s? for example:

```
Matrix A is a 3x3 with eigenvalues: 0,1,-1 and eigenvectors: [1,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,1]

would the diagonal matrix be 0 0 0
                             0 1 0
                             0 0 -1

 ??
```

Comment: @Amzoti sorry that was a typo. But is the logic correct? given the eigenvalues, the diagonal matrix is just the identity matrix with the eigenvalues swapped for the values of the 1s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue, our diagonal matrix is:

$$J = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

We can now write $P$ using the eigenvectors as column vectors that follow their respective eigenvalues as:

$$P =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Lastly, we can write:

$$A^3 = PJ^3P^{-1}$$

Finding $J^3$ is just a matter of writing $\lambda_i^3$ in the diagonal entries of $J$.

You might want to review [*Diagonalizable Matrices*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) and these [*notes*](https://www.math.okstate.edu/~binegar/3013-S99/3013-l16.pdf).

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't make this clear enough. My main goal wasn't to solve the actual problem but finding the diagonal matrix. Every problem i've done so far had the diagonal matrix to just be a matrix with the eigenvalues in the diagonal entries. Can you tell me if this is a coincidence or a property of diagonal matrices?